# How can i sort my dataframe with the most recent value at the bottom?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    df=pd.read_csv("BTC-USD.csv")
    df=df.drop(["Date","Adj Close","Volume","Low","Close"],axis=1)
    x=df["Open"]
    y=df["High"]
```

[Here is my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VlRQ.png)

In my data frame , newest value is at the top. What i wanna do here is putting newest value to bottom and oldest value to top.

Comment: post code, not pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you just want to inverse line order without considering values in columns.
Thus, you need to use pandas.DataFrame.reindex function as follow:

```
reordered_df = df.reindex(df.index[::-1])
```

The documentation is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html